# Hide/Show Load function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a script that shows 2 divs and hides 1 div after a user submits a form. The form's target is an Iframe on the same page.

I would like to delay the Hide/Show events until the Iframe loads. I was able to do this with a loading animation, but I am not sure how to do this with the Hide/Show script.

The script works with the submit function like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#form_710370').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); // add this
       $('#form_container').hide()
       $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
       return false;
    });
});
```

But if I try to use the load function like this, it does not work, but it works for my loading animation, any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#iframe1').load(function(){
  {
    $('#form_container').hide()
      $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show()
     });
```

This is the loading animation script which works

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#iframe1').on('load', function () {
    $('#loader1').hide();
        });
    });
    / in ready()
    $('#form_710370').submit(function(){$('#loader1').show();return true;});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="mydivhide1">1111</div>
<div id="mydivhide2">2222</div>

<div id="form_container">
    <form id="form_710370"  target="iframe" method="post" convert.php">
        <input id="Website" name="url1" type="text" value=""/> 
        <input id="saveForm" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form> 
</div>

<div id="frameWrap">
<img id="loader1" src="ajax_loader_blue_512.gif" alt="loading gif"/>  
    <iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="page.html" > </iframe>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#mydivhide1 {display:none;}
#mydivhide2 {display:none;}
```

Comment: In general terms, it's better if you don't preventDefault() for the form itself, but instead do it for the form's submit button, on the other hand it seems your problem could easily be solved via a Timeout callback.

Comment: @JoseE Could you show me how to do that in the vode? I am just learning Jquery and have not done that before, thanks

Comment: I think that you can start trying this answer first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788499/jquery-iframe-load-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you're running into is that you're preventing the form from submitting to the `iframe` which is then showing the `div`s but the `iframe` is never calling `load` again because the submit is being stopped.

Assuming that you want to show `#mydivhide1` and `#mydivhide2` when the form is submitted and then hide them when the `iframe` finishes loading, I came up with a fiddle that should do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/CST4t/3/

Basically I just removed the `e.preventDefault( );` and instead of returning `false`, I returned `true` so the form submission went through.  I also cleaned up some items like the form `action` attribute and moved the `submit` function override to `$(document).ready( );`.

**Edit**

One other thing that I did was I changed the `form` `target` and the name of the `iframe` to a more commonly used name that seems to work better across more browsers. Apparently the name and target values are really touchy from browser to browser, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14882630/2620930).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just checked the fiddle, yes the form works, but it does not do the main point of the script. I want to hide   `<div id="form_container">` after the load and also open the other two `#mydivhide1` & `#mydivhide2`  when it is finished loading.

Comment: Ahh I misunderstood a portion of your question. How's this? http://jsfiddle.net/CST4t/4/

Comment: Thanks bro, I think that is going to work, going to add it into the real page now and test it!

Comment: No problemo. I hope it works out for you in your application!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#iframe1').contents().load(function() {
    //window loaded
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried that, but the hide/show function does not work when I change it to `$('#iframe1').contents().load(function() {
    //window loaded`
});'